# Sending email in php using localhost

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am having a bit of a problem getting to send an email from the localhost and kindly need your help. This is the error message I have been getting:

> Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:"
>   header missing in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\send_mail.php on line 22.

[image: This is my php.ini file]

[image: This is my sendmail.php file]

[image: This is my sendmail.ini file]

Please assist

Comment: You can't send mail from `localhost`. You have to use server with proper settings.

Comment: @Harish Kommuri; You can send mail from `localhost` by using `phpmailer`

Comment: Do not post images of code. Post it properly and format it

Comment: @RamaLingam even with `mail()` you can still can, you just need to configure it the ryt way.

Comment: @Masivuye; Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your mail format is wrong

```
mail($email_address,$subject,$msg,$header);
```

Answer (score 0):

To send email using localhost you need to configure localhost to send emails.

The followings steps are to send email using localhost with `xampp` and `sendmail`

You can send mail from localhost with sendmail package , sendmail package is inbuild in XAMPP. So if you are using XAMPP then you can easily send mail from localhost.

for example you can configure `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` for gmail to send mail.

in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini find extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

in `php.ini` file find `[mail function]` and change

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Replace all the existing code in sendmail.ini with following code

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=your-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=your-gmail-password
force_sender=your-gmail-id@gmail.com
Then you are done :)
```

remember to restart the server using the XAMMP control panel so the changes take effect. Happy coding :)

By the way your mail function is incorrect

it should be

`mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);`